# Could not create constraint or index

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running this SQL statement

```
CREATE TABLE TblPeminjaman
(
    KodePeminjaman varchar(4) PRIMARY KEY,
    KodeBuku varchar(4) NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY (KodeBuku) REFERENCES TblPeminjaman (KodePeminjaman),
    NIM varchar(9) NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY (NIM) REFERENCES TblPeminjaman (KodePeminjaman),
    TglPinjam Date NOT NULL,
    TglKembali Date NOT NULL,
    Status varchar(10) NOT NULL
        CHECK (Status = 'Kembali' OR Status = 'Pinjam')
);

INSERT INTO dbo.TblPeminjaman (KodePeminjaman, KodeBuku, NIM, TglPinjam, TglKembali, Status)
VALUES ('P002', 'BU04', 182112222, '17/03/2021', '23/03/2021', 'Pinjam')
```

I'm getting this error:

> Msg 1753, Level 16, State 0, Line 83
> Column 'TblPeminjaman.KodePeminjaman' is not the same length or scale as referencing column 'TblPeminjaman.NIM' in foreign key 'FK__TblPeminjam__NIM__208CD6FA'. Columns participating in a foreign key relationship must be defined with the same length and scale.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 83
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Please help me

Comment: you have a foreign key to a column on the same table. The error is telling you both those columns need to be the same length, either `varchar(4)` or `varchar(9)`. (I don't think them being on the same table matters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have defined column "NIM" as  varchar(9) while its reference column KodePeminjaman in table TblPeminjaman has different size or type

based on that your other fk to the same table/column looks ok , NIM column should be varchar(4)

```
Create Table TblPeminjaman
(KodePeminjaman varchar(4) primary key,
KodeBuku varchar(4) not null Foreign Key (KodeBuku) References TblPeminjaman (KodePeminjaman),
NIM varchar(4) not null Foreign Key (NIM) References TblPeminjaman (KodePeminjaman),
TglPinjam Date not null,
TglKembali Date not null,
Status varchar(10) not null Check(Status='Kembali' OR Status='Pinjam'));
```